# Reseting the values of a sigset in C

Tags: c, linux

I've been trying to create this parallel program in which the parent holds a counter, and if that counter reaches a value that is divisible by 10, then I'll send to the child program the signal SIGUSR1, to which the son must reply by printing something. Also if the program gets the signal SIGINT, the son will end its execution, followed by the father ending its execution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

void handler_sigusr1(int nr_sem){
    //fprintf(stderr,"Debug: procesul cu PID-ul %d a primit semnalul de notificare.\n", getpid());
}

int main() {
    sigset_t  base_mask, waiting_mask;
    int pid;

    sigemptyset(&base_mask);
    sigaddset(&base_mask, SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&base_mask, SIGUSR2);
    sigaddset(&base_mask, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&base_mask, SIGPIPE);

    signal(SIGUSR1,handler_sigusr1);
    signal(SIGUSR2,handler_sigusr1);
    signal(SIGINT,handler_sigusr1);
    signal(SIGPIPE,handler_sigusr1);

    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &base_mask, NULL);

    if ( -1 == (pid = fork())){
        perror("Eroare la fork: ");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pid == 0){//daca suntem in fiu
        //if (sigsuspend(&mask_usr1_deblocat) == 0 ||  sigsuspend(&mask_usr2_deblocat) == 0){
        while(1) {
            sigpending(&waiting_mask);
            if (sigismember(&waiting_mask, SIGUSR1)) {
                printf("Fiul: am primit USR1 \n");
                fflush(stdout);
                sigemptyset(&waiting_mask);
            }
            else if (sigismember(&waiting_mask, SIGUSR2)) {
                printf("Fiul: sfarsit executie \n");
                fflush(stdout);
                kill(getppid(), SIGPIPE);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else{//daca suntem in parinte
        int contor = 0;
        for(int i=1;1<2;i++){
            contor+=i;
            printf("Contor = %d\n", contor);
            fflush(stdout);
            sleep(1);
            if (contor % 10 == 0){
                kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
            }
            sigpending(&waiting_mask);
            if (sigismember(&waiting_mask, SIGINT)){
                kill(pid, SIGUSR2);
            }
            if (sigismember(&waiting_mask, SIGPIPE)){
                printf("S-a terminat executia!");
                fflush(stdout);
                exit(2);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I've written until now, and I don't know why the sigemptyset in the son part of the program doesn't clear the waiting_set, thus printing my message indefinitely.

Comment: _Side note:_ SysV IPC `msgsnd/msgrcv` is probably a better way to communicate. Doing `*printf` in a signal handler is _not_ signal safe

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know why the sigemptyset in the son part of the program doesn't clear the waiting_set

But *the son part of the program* **does** *clear the* `waiting_mask`, and nothing else, i. e. it only sets the variable *to empty*, which has no impact at all on the set of pending signals. To clear the pending SIGUSR1, we can

```
                signal(SIGUSR1, SIG_IGN);
```

instead.